# How to get unique record by multi-attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model like this:
    Order(id: integer, user_id: integer, target_id: integer, content: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)

It belongs to User. User can make order for each other like:

- person A -> person B
- person B -> person A
- person A -> person B

=> The unique record should be A -> B, so how can I filter Order to unique record ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "A -> B" or "B -> A", can you explain it another way?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I mean person A can create order to person B and vice versa.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "filter Order to unique record?" Are you looking for a query that returns, say, all orders made by user A where the target is user B?

Comment: @jmschles I mean it'll return only one order that made between user A and user B ( even if user A send many order to user B and user B aslo make order for user A)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To make it easier for other users to help you, please include some code, preferably in the form of a [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). See also [How to Ask](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, assuming you have users A and B, you should just be able to do this:

```
Order.where(user: A, target: B)
```

...assuming you've defined your associations, otherwise:

```
Order.where(user_id: A.id, target_id: B.id)
```

EDIT: just saw your comment. You could add `.first` to either of the above queries just to get the first order if you wanted to.

ANOTHER EDIT: As I understand it, if there's ever been one or more orders between A and B (or B and A), you want to grab one of them, and you don't care which. You could do this:

```
(Order.where(user: A, target: B) + Order.where(user: B, target: A)).first
```

That will give you a record if one exists and `nil` if it doesn't.  Raw SQL would be more efficient:

```
Order.where("user_id = ? AND target_id = ? OR user_id = ? AND target_id = ?", A.id, B.id, B.id, A.id).first
```

... but less readable, and be sure to test it. Good luck!

Comment: This query will not return unique record. I used:  `Order.uniq.pluck(:user_id, :target_id)`  which return:  `[[1,2],[1,14],[3,5],[1,23],[2,1],...]`  So Is there any way that I can query the unique order using this array ?!

Comment: I'm still having trouble understanding what you mean by "unique record". It sounds like you're saying there could be multiple orders with the same user and target. So let's say your query above returned `[[1,2],[1,2]]`. If you want to query for one or the other, you need a field that differentiates them somehow. Otherwise you just have to do something arbitrary like grab the first or last one.

Comment: Hmmm... As your new update. So what if the Order that have (user_id: B, target_id: A) ?! It'will return another record right ?!

Comment: Yup, that's a different query and will only return orders where the user is B and the target is A.

Comment: Ok. To be clearer. My project helps user A get phone number of user B and user B also can get phone number of user A (some kind of matching people). I build a dashboard to check that they are matching or not. As you see, whether the order from A or B or how many time they made order, it's just a connection between 2 people. That's why I want to get a unique record